# Python add next item as key in dictionary when counter is incremented

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this python function which takes data from excel file and print when a id is found:

```
values = []
dict = {}
for rowidx in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    row = int(sheet['A' + str(rowidx)].value)
    if row in [10,11,30]:
        show = sheet[str(rowidx)]
        #print show
        key =  sheet.cell(row=rowidx, column=1).value
        for cells in show:
            values.append(cells.value)
            dict[key] = values
        print values
        print dict
```

The output to this function is :

```
{10L: [10L, u'jhon', u'abc', u'wa@gmail.com', None, 11L, u'smith', u'xyz', u'sa@gmail.com', None], 11L: [10L, u'jhon', u'abc', u'wa@gmail.com', None, 11L, u'smith', u'xyz', u'sa@gmail.com', None]}
```

Although this adds id as key to dictionary but appends whole of the list to each key. I want to break the list when `rowidx` incremented and then add new key and start the list again like this:

```
{10L: [10L, u'jhon', u'abc', u'wa@gmail.com', None]}
{11L: [11L, u'smith', u'xyz', u'sa@gmail.com', None]}
```

Also removing the first item in the list as it is already added as key.

**Update** 
I moved dict[key] = values outside the loop and got this output

```
{10L: [u'jhon', u'abc', u'wa@gmail.com', None], 11L: [u'jhon', u'abc', u'wa@gmail.com', None, 11L, u'smith', u'xyz', u'sa@gmail.com', None]}
```

I think emptying the list after each iteration should do the work

Comment: please provide the data you used to generate your output

Comment: You are sharing the same `values` list everywhere.  Move that into the loop so you create a new list each time you need it.

Comment: why `dict[key] = values` is in the loop? it's useless since `values` doesn't change in the loop (and neither does `key`)

Comment: its an excel file. But how file that file is going to help. I just want to cut the list and start a new one with a new key when rowidx is incremented

Comment: *Also removing the first item in the list as it is already added as key.*  If you know your rows will always have the same format, you can do `dict[key] = values[1:]` or perhaps `dict[key] = [x for x in values if x != key]`.

Comment: @0x5453 yes that can be done but how can I cut the list. I tried by moving dict[key] = values outside the loop but that didn't help

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how about flushig contents of list after each iteration

Comment: `dict[key]` holds the same reference to `values`. The contents don't matter.

Comment: But I got the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the contents of the list after each iteration did the work.

```
values = []
dict = {}
for rowidx in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    row = int(sheet['A' + str(rowidx)].value)
    if row in [10,11,30]:
        show = sheet[str(rowidx)]
        print show
        key =  sheet.cell(row=rowidx, column=1).value
        for cells in show:
            values.append(cells.value)
            dict[key] = values[1:]
        del values[:]

print dict
```

Output:

```
{10L: [u'jhon', u'abc', u'wa@gmail.com', None], 11L: [u'smith', u'xyz', u'sa@gmail.com', None]}
```

Comment: Note that the reason this works is because slicing (`values[1:]`) makes a *copy* of the list, so the dictionary items are no longer sharing references to the same list.  If you weren't doing the slice, your delete solution would not work, because you would be clearing *all* of the lists through that reference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When I got this solution worked I was also surprised but I never noticed that I sliced the list. Should I  add this in answer.